# replace <xml> tag data with empty javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I am having string contents `<xml>.....</xml>`
I want to replace xml tag with its inner content with the empty string.
How can I achieve it by regular expression or javascript.

My Code is  -

```
var tempHtml =  "Test Data Test Data<br>Test data Test Data data ata<br>data<br><br>Testerbr><br><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA </xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> CCCCCCCCCCCCC </xml><![endif]--> here data";


ht = ht.replace("<xml>(.+?)<\/xml>/gi", "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex just needed to be modified, alongside with using the right variable name:

```
var tempHtml =  "Test Data Test Data<br>Test data Test Data data ata<br>data<br><br>Testerbr><br><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA </xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> CCCCCCCCCCCCC </xml><![endif]--> here data";
tempHtml = tempHtml.replace(/<xml>(.+?)<\/xml>/gi, "");
// Now tempHtml = "Test Data Test Data<br>Test data Test Data data ata<br>data<br><br>Testerbr><br><!--[if gte mso 9]><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><![endif]--> here data"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: But not this is  not working with my actual string. Actual string is too big will share with you in couple of minutes

Comment: can you share the "actual string" ?

Comment: In the code linked, the regex is wrapped with double quotes ("). Remove the double quotes so the second line will be `tempHtml  = tempHtml .replace(/<xml>(.+?)<\/xml>/gi, "");`.

Comment: thanks again Still one problem just come to knoe Its working fine in chrome but not  in my mozilla (little old version 40.0.3 ) Can you pleas check.

Comment: Well, I can see it is working here: https://www.browserling.com/browse/win/7/firefox/40/https%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2Fq8n83zxz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140240/discussion-between-saurabh-mahajan-and-hossam).

Comment: are you looking in that?

Comment: got the problem that my string contains \r\n thats why i was not able to replace.